# Short story, child time travels when dreaming, finds another child who believes he was created by robots

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, robots

I remember reading a story about a kid who lives in an old Frank Lloyd Wright house after mankind has returned to Earth after leaving for a time. He meets another boy whenever he sleeps, this other boy believes he is a machine and that robots (who order the child around) are the ones who have families and they created him. It is actually a plot by the robots to figure out how to make more of themselves by studying a human child. In the end, the kid realizes he was time traveling into the past to help the other child after his father tells him how all the robots broke down, allowing mankind to reclaim Earth.

I can't remember who wrote it but I read it in a high school sci-fi anthology collection in 1979, or maybe 1980.

Comment: Whilst the user who edited this may have changed the meaning, I don't know haven't checked, editing is a vital concept of stack exchange, see the [help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing) for more info.

Comment: Cannot remember the book, but I do remember it had two other stories in in. A boy learns to fly after his uncle uses a machine to alter his brain and then does battle in the skies with stingray like creatures that hide in the clouds with a handheld laser. Also a boy is taken by aliens and interrogated in a VR simulation but escapes by using some matches. I will try to track it down but hope this helps.

Comment: I don't mind editing for style, grammar, flow, etc... but the context should remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a story in *More Science Fiction Tales* edited by Roger Elwood.  Here is a link describing one of the short stories “The Bend of Time”.

[More Science Fiction Tales](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2013/07/more-science-fiction-tales-roger-elwood.html?m=1)

> In **The Bend of Time** (William Danton), a boy returning to a recolonized Earth in the year 4010 is able to communicate across time with another boy his age from a prior millenium, when the world was ruled by robots called Ogolots.

The time period of 1974 is correct as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Vicpylon!  You are my hero.